# Tcl - How to read a nested variable from inside a procedure

Tags: tcl

I am trying to do the following:

```
set myvar_key something
set a myvar
proc test {} {
  # I am expecting mylocal_var to be "something", but it errors
  set mylocal_var [set ${::a}_key]
}

# The proc is called like this
test
```

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but just missed something. As your code already shows, `a` is in the global namespace, thus you need `::a`.
Same is true for `myvar_key`, thus you need to do

```
set myvar_key something
set a myvar
proc test {} {
  set mylocal_var [set ::${::a}_key]
  puts $mylocal_var
}
test
```

prints "something"

Comment: Any any time you're using the name of a variable like that, consider using `upvar` or an array.

Answer (score 3):

In these sorts of scenarios, it tends to be easier to use `upvar` to make a local alias for a variable in another scope. Yes, you can do trickery with `set` and such, but it tends to be harder to use, especially in real code. Once you've done the `upvar`, the local name is just another (*highly* efficient) way of accessing the named variable in another scope.

```
set myvar_key something
set a myvar
proc test {} {
     # The #0 is quoted *just* for Stack Overflow's highlighting!
     upvar "#0" ${::a}_key mylocal_var
}
```

If you were willing to rearrange your variables, you could instead do:

```
set key(myvar) something
set a myvar
proc test {} {
    global a key
    set mylocal_var $key($a)
}
```

But that does change what the main variable is so it isn't suitable in all cases. And you can do hybrids:

```
set key(myvar) something
set a myvar
proc test {} {
    upvar "#0" key($::a) mylocal_var
}
```